# How to make a variable behave like a reference or a value hook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

To specific, here is a `class A`, which has a member `var` storing some intermediate result. What I want to do is trying to make a wrapper which have an instance of `A()` as a member, but still accessing `var` without changing other part of code.

Pseudo-Code:

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=0
        ....

Class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.submod=A()

instance_b = B()
```

and make `instance_b.var` refers to `instance_b.submod.var` as it changes while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work for you

```
 Class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.submod = A()

        @property    
        def var(self):
            return self.submod.var
```

Comment: Adding appropriate `@var.setter` and `@var.deleter` methods should the `var` need to be writable.

Comment: Ecellent! I checked python docs and find that I've neglected the decrorators for so long. Thank your for such elegant solution and reminding me of these things.